# .htaccess redirects aren't respecting my regex

Tags: regex, .htaccess, query-string

I need to redirect any requests with query strings from a set of origin URLs back to a thank you page.

For example, I need to redirect:
`http://example.com/test1/test2/[origin]/?id=1`
back to
`http://example.com/thank-you`

The way I've got it set up in my .htaccess file is as such:

```
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch 302 ^/test1/test2/(.*)/.+ /thank-you
```

I've tested the regex I'm using in an online regex tester and it appears to work as expected, so I'm confused as to why the redirect isn't taking place.  [Here's the link to that.](https://www.regextester.com/108509)

Obviously, I had to add backslashes to escape the slashes in the URL in the regex tester, but based on my understanding of how .htaccess evaluates regex, these aren't necessary.

My question is: the redirect works perfectly from the page without the query string if I remove the `.+` from the end of the regex string, meaning that the beginning part of the regex works fine.  I don't understand why the query string isn't matching the regex I've created.

I have also tried:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/test1/test2/(.*)/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /thank-you [R=302,L]
```

Comment: No, .htaccess doesn't use double quotes, it just uses unescaped spaces to separate arguments.

Comment: Your second set of code (RewriteRule) could work with flags `[R=302,L,QSD]`.

Comment: @IanCZane your second rules , only add ? after target thank-you like this thank-you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your RedirectMatch, you may use:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/test1/test2/(.*)/(.*)+ /thank-you?
```

For your RewriteRule section, you may use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/test1/test2/(.*)/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /thank-you [R=302,L,QSD]
```

Answer (score 0):

First , no need to `RewriteEngine On` with `mod_alias` which is `RedirectMatch` at your rules use it with `mod_rewrite` , the second rules .

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^test1/test2/[^\/]+/$ /thank-you? [R=302,L]
```

I use `^id=([0-9]+)$` to restrict query string for a one that start with `id` and end with `numerical value`.

I remove this line `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/test1/test2/(.*)/` becasue you could match against URI in `RewriteRule` as well.

If this rules wrok , change `[R=302,L]` to `[R=301,L]` to be permanent redirection.

**Note:** clear browser cache then test